# Endpointelement not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, soap, wsdl, app-config

I have never worked with SOAP, so maybe it is something obvious that I am missing but can someone tell me what there has to be in the app.config when I am using this wsdl as connected services in visual studio with this wsdl.

Currently in the app.config this is my data :

```
<configuration>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
</startup>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="academieAPISoap">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
            <binding name="academieAPISoap1" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://tryout.academieportal.nl/api2.0/academieAPI_2.0.php"
            binding="netHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration="academieAPISoap"
            contract="AcAPI.academieAPISoap" name="academieAPISoap"/>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

the wsdl url: http://tryout.academieportal.nl/api2.0/academieAPI_2.0.php?wsdl .
The connected service is saved with the name AcAPI.

the error that I am getting:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find
>   default endpoint element that references contract
>   'AcAPI.academieAPISoap' in the ServiceModel client configuration
>   section. This might be because no configuration file was found for
>   your application, or because no endpoint element matching this
>   contract could be found in the client element.
>
> at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadChannelBehaviors(ServiceEndpoint
>   serviceEndpoint, String configurationName)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration(String
>   configurationName, Configuration configuration)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration(String
>   configurationName)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint(String
>   configurationName, EndpointAddress address)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(String
>   endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ConfigurationEndpointTrait`1.CreateSimplexFactory()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.ConfigurationEndpointTrait`1.CreateChannelFactory()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelFactoryRef(EndpointTrait`1
>   endpointTrait)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.InitializeChannelFactoryRef()    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1..ctor()    at
>   AcademieApiCall.SoapApiClient..ctor(String user, String pass) in
>   C:\Users\Gebruiker\source\repos\AcademieApiCall\AcademieApiCall\SoapApiClient.cs:line
>   16    at AcademieApiCall.DataHandler..ctor() in
>   C:\Users\Gebruiker\source\repos\AcademieApiCall\AcademieApiCall\dataHandler.cs:line
>   22    at AcademieApiCall.Program.ExecuteCsv(String path) in
>   C:\Users\Gebruiker\source\repos\AcademieApiCall\AcademieApiCall\Program.cs:line
>   33    at AcademieApiCall.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\Users\Gebruiker\source\repos\AcademieApiCall\AcademieApiCall\Program.cs:line
>   26

Update:
If I add the reference as a web reference then I get other kinds off objects and functions. Can someone explain how that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App.config has to be present in the release or debug folder.